# If you assign an Object to a final field, will other threads see previous updates of that Object's non-final/non-volatile fields?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, volatile

Reading the Java language specs, I found this excerpt about final fields:

> The usage model for final fields is a simple one: Set the final fields
>   for an object in that object's constructor; and do not write a
>   reference to the object being constructed in a place where another
>   thread can see it before the object's constructor is finished. If this
>   is followed, then when the object is seen by another thread, that
>   thread will always see the correctly constructed version of that
>   object's final fields. **It will also see versions of any object or
>   array referenced by those final fields that are at least as up-to-date
>   as the final fields are**.

Link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5

My question is, does "versions" mean updates? This means that the non-final/non-volatile fields of an object referenced by a final field will also be read from main memory (not the local cache) after construction?

---

**Example**

So let's say `thread #1` creates an `objectB` and sets one of its non-final/non-volatile fields.

Then `thread #2` sets that same field to something different, creates some other `objectA` with a final field set as `objectB`, then puts that `objectA` somewhere where `thread #1` can get it.

`thread #1` then gets the `objectA`, and sees its final field as `objectB`. Is it possible for `thread #1` to not see the changes to `objectB` made by `thread #2`?

Or here is some code showing what I mean:

```
public class Test {
    private static final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<A> myAs = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    private static long timer = System.nanoTime() + 3000000000L; // 3 seconds into the future

    public static void main(String... args) {
        B myB = new B("thread #1"); // Set in thread 1

        new Thread(() -> {
            myB.setString("thread #2"); // Set in thread 2
            myAs.add(new A(myB));
        }).start();

        for(long i = 0; i < x; i = System.nanoTime()) {} // Busy-wait for about 3 seconds

        System.out.println(myAs.poll().getB().getString()); // Print out value
    }

    public static class A {
        private final B b;

        public A(B b) {
            this.b = b;
        }

        public B getB() {
            return b;
        }
    }

    public static class B {
        private String s = null;

        public B(String s) {
            this.s = s;
        }

        public String getString() {
            return s;
        }

        public void setString(String s) {
            this.s = s;
        }
    }
}
```

The code seems to read the updated values, but I'm not sure if that's just out of random luck.

Comment: Pretty good for the first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO you will always see the updated value.. There are 2 things which are happening here

1. Safe publication
2. Freeze action at the end of the constructor

As we have a freeze action other thread should be able to see the content of myB

More details :
https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/jmm-pragmatics/#_part_v_finals

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp03304/index.html

Answer (score 0):

"Is it possible for `thread #1` to not see the changes to `objectB` made by `thread #2`?"

Yes. Because `thread #1` can cache value.

Quote from spec mean that there is `happened before` between assignment of final field value and publishing of object.

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting and I think I've actually read about it a while ago... Here is an example (if I remember correctly the example):

```
 static class Holder {

    private final String[] names;

    static Holder newHolder;

    public Holder() {
        super();
        names = new String[3];
        names[0] = "first";
        names[1] = "last";
    }

    public void newObject() {
        newHolder = new Holder();
        newHolder.names[2] = "oneMore";
    }

    public void readObject() {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newHolder.names));
    }

}
```

Suppose you have two threads involved here: `ThreadA` and `ThreadB`. And now also suppose that `ThreadA` invokes `newObject`; when it's done `ThreadB` invokes `readObject`.

There are absolutely no guarantees that `ThreadB` will print `first, last, oneMore`; it is only guaranteed that `first` and `last` will be present for sure.

This btw is perfectly understandable once you think in terms of `MemoryBarriers` that are used in case of `final fields used inside constructor`.

Under the current implementation, this *actually* looks like this:

```
public Holder() {
    super();
    names = new String[3];
    names[0] = "first";
    names[1] = "last";
}
// [StoreStore]
// [LoadStore]
```

there are two barriers that are inserted at the end of the constrcutor   that prevent other reads and stores to happen.